# Получить родительский контроллер в презентуемом контроллере

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

Имея три контроллера (FirstControler, SecondController и ThirdController) мне нужно:

1. в FirstContoller презентовать SecondController.
2. в SecondController по нажатию скрыть себя (SecondController) и показать ThirdController на FirstController (это все должно быть в SecondController).

Мне нужно обратиться к FirstController в SecondController после того как я сделаю

```
class FirstController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let secondController = SecondController()
        present(secondController, animated: true)

    }

}

class SecondController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //ТУТ ПОЛУЧИТЬ FistController (контроллер в котором я презентовал этот контроллер)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого воспользуйтесь свойством `presentingViewController`

Comment: оно возвращает мне  nil

Comment: точнее оно работает например во ViewDidAppear, но во viewDidLoad и в методах после ViewDidAppear оно равно nil и по этому приходится записывать в переменную

Comment: @Artem делать `present` во `viewDidLoad` в принципе не такая уж и хорошая идея, о чем нас предупреждает Apple (см. в консоль во время вызова `present` во `viewDidLoad`)

Comment: это лишь мой пример, я так на самом деле не делаю, вопрос в том почему presentingViewController равен nil

Comment: @Artem Когда вызывается `viewDidLoad`, нет никакой гарантии, что иерархия контроллера представления загружается в дерево навигации. Перемещение логики на более поздний этап (например: `viewWillAppear`) должно решить эту проблему, поскольку к тому времени контроллер представления должен быть загружен. Если мой ответ был исчерпывающим, отметьте его как ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: у меня есть событие, которое выполняется после viewDidAppear и при этом в самом viewDidAppear presentingViewController не равен nil, а в методе после него равен nil, из-за этого я вынужден во viewDidAppear записывать в переменную значение свойства presentingViewController, чтобы использовать дальше в своем методе

Comment: @Artem это вопрос или ?.. Вам необязательно записывать в переменную значение этого свойства. Если оно определено один раз, то будет храниться там до самого конца существования второго view controller'а. Я только что проверил это. Если у вас это не так, пожалуйста, предоставьте ваш код, будем разбираться

Comment: `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     print("TEST_1", presentingViewController)
}
func pickerListener(completion: @escaping((Data) -> Void)) {
     callback.subscribe { [self] data in
          print("TEST_2", presentingViewController)
     }
}`
<br/>
Мой ответ в консоли
TEST_1 Optional(<***.TabBar: 0x113817800>)
TEST_2 nil

Comment: я пытался написать, но получилось не очень. В общем presentingViewController есть во viewDidAppear, а в калбэке после (когда он уже есть) он равен nil. Могу сделать скрин, но не знаю куда его вставить

Comment: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1425693/presentingviewcontroller-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd-nil-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8] задал новый вопрос